# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Item ID'

Tags: vb.net

This error 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Item ID'.' always comes up when I try add data into the database. Can anyone help? Thanks

```
 Private Sub RefreshData()
    If Not cnn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection
        cnn.Open()
    End If

    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT Item ID as [Item ID], " & _
                                         "Item Name as [Item Name], " & _
                                         "Item Type as [Item Type], " & _
                                         "Quantity as [Quantity], " & _
                                         "Min Shelf Stock as [Min Shelf Stock], " & _
                                         "Purchase Price as [Purchase Price], Note " & _
                                         " From Product ORDER BY Item ID", cnn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    'fill data to datatable 
    da.Fill(dt)

    'offer data in data table into datagridview
    Me.dgvData.DataSource = dt

    'Close the connection
    cnn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: You have spaces in your column names...

Comment: In the table I have created in Access the table columns have spaces therefore I have matched them. What would you recommend

Answer (score 1):

Put [] around your column names. Ex: Item Id = [Item Id]
do that for all your Column names

```
SELECT Item ID as [Item ID], " & _
                                     "Item Name as [Item Name], " & _
                                     "Item Type as [Item Type], " & _
                                     "Quantity as [Quantity], " & _
                                     "Min Shelf Stock as [Min Shelf Stock], " & _
                                     "Purchase Price as [Purchase Price], Note " & _
                                     " From Product ORDER BY Item ID",
```

change to:

```
SELECT [Item ID], " & _
                                     "[Item Name], " & _
                                     "[Item Type], " & _
                                     "[Quantity], " & _
                                     "[Min Shelf Stock], " & _
                                     "[Purchase Price], Note " & _
                                     " From Product ORDER BY Item ID",
```

Comment: It was coming, slow typing